# Edit comment language

Tags: discussion, editing, comments

I recently stumbled upon [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/posts/206769/revisions) edit with the following comment `仕方が無い`.

Which google translate inform me transliterate to `Shikata ga nai`. While a descriptive comment for the edit performed (correcting the spelling), I think that we shouldn't have to use any translating tool to understand an edit justification (at least putting a transliteration of non-latin words).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While in general I agree - this is an English speaking site and we should ensure that all comments etc are in English - in this specific instance Shikata ga nai is the name of the tool that the editor correctly edited in to the post, along with some other good edits. So I wouldn't be too concerned this time.

To the editor - please stick to English next time.

Answer (score 2):

I was the one who made the edit. I had meant to have the edit comment to explain that I corrected the spelling by using something like `仕方が無い - Shikata ga nai`, but for some reason I just posted the Japanese text and not the romaji. Not sure why, I must have been in a hurry. It was my bad.